# Wxpython grid AppendRows

Tags: grid, wxpython

The following code is used to generate a table that an row can be added by a button, but only the data of the last row is eliminated after running.

```
import wx, wx.grid
class GridData(wx.grid.PyGridTableBase):
        _cols = "a b c".split()
        _data = [
        "1 2 3".split(),
        "4 5 6".split(),
        "7 8 9".split()
        ]
        _highlighted = set()

        def GetColLabelValue(self, col):
            return self._cols[col]

        def GetNumberRows(self):
            return len(self._data)

        def GetNumberCols(self):
            return len(self._cols)

        def GetValue(self, row, col):
            return self._data[row][col]

        def SetValue(self, row, col, val):
            self._data[row][col] = val

        def AppendRows(self, *args):
            msg = wx.grid.GridTableMessage(self,
                                       wx.grid.GRIDTABLE_NOTIFY_ROWS_APPENDED,
                                           )
            self.GetView().ProcessTableMessage(msg)
            return True
            # self.GetView().EndBatch()
            # msg = wx.grid.GridTableMessage(self, wx.grid.GRIDTABLE_REQUEST_VIEW_GET_VALUES)
            # self.GetView().ProcessTableMessage(msg)

        def GetAttr(self, row, col, kind):
            attr = wx.grid.GridCellAttr()
            attr.SetBackgroundColour(wx.GREEN if row in self._highlighted else wx.WHITE)
            return attr

        def set_value(self, row, col, val):
            self._highlighted.add(row)
            self.SetValue(row, col, val)


class Test(wx.Frame):#main frame
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)

        self.data = GridData()
        self.grid = wx.grid.Grid(self)
        self.grid.SetTable(self.data)

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="set a2 to x")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnTest)

        self.Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.Sizer.Add(self.grid, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.Sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.EXPAND)

   def OnTest(self, event):
        self.grid.AppendRows(numRows=3)
        #self.data.set_value(1, 0, "x")
        self.grid.Refresh()

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
app.TopWindow = Test()
app.TopWindow.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

There is no error report,and the expectation can't be reached.
The following code is used to generate a table that can be added by a button, but only the data of the last row can be eliminated after running.